# Combine file API with transactions for file saving or deleting

Tags: node.js, file-upload, transactions, pg-promise

I am using node 8.11.1 with [pg-promise 8.4.4](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example) to handle queries and transactions in PostgreSQL. This is about node, but I guess is the same logic in other servers/tools too.

The scenario is common. I want to save an image file in a folder, then if this is successful, insert its details in the database, get the returned id and then do another insert in a secondary, many-to-many table.

Clearly, I need a transaction for the insert queries. But what about the actual file saving? My approach is

```
fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, (err) => {
  if (err){throw new Error ;}            
      db.tx('my-transaction', t => {
        return t.one('INSERT INTO images(whatever) VALUES($1) RETURNING id', ['whatever'])
        .then(user => {
          return t.batch([
            t.none('INSERT INTO mtm(userId, name) VALUES($1, $2)', [user.id, 'created'])
          ]);
        });
      })
      .then(data => {
          // success          
      })
      .catch(error => {
          // error
      });
}); //fs rename
```

Ok, if there is no error while saving the image file with `fs.rename`, then proceed with the transaction.

If there is an error while saving the image, nothing will execute, so all good.

**But the problem is**, what if the image is saved and there is an error in the transaction? I will end up with an image saved and nothing in the database. Sure, user will get an error and will have to re-upload, but **I still have images in my server that are not related to anything.** I would like to avoid this.

The solution would be to incorporate the image saving in the transaction, so if anything fails, nothing is completed. How can I do this? I dont know if the file API can be inside a query-related transaction. I dont even know if I am in the right mindset here.

Please advice or help me code this.

Thank you

Comment: If transaction fails, just delete the file. Also, best is to use [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra), which includes promise support, so the code is consistent.

Comment: I have added a detailed answer below. Please accept, if you are happy with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the file, if transaction fails (or you can rename it back, if you prefer):

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

async function saveAll(oldpath, newpath) {
    await fs.rename(oldpath, newpath);
    try {
        return await db.tx('my-transaction', async t => {
            const imageId = await t.one('INSERT INTO images(whatever) VALUES($1) RETURNING id', ['whatever'], a => a.id);
            await t.none('INSERT INTO mtm(userId, name) VALUES($1, $2)', [imageId, 'created']);
            return imageId;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        await fs.unlink(newpath); // deleting the file
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Function `saveAll` will return the new `imageId`, if successful, or throw an error, if anything fails:

```
async test() {
    try {
        const imageId = await saveAll('old-path', 'new-path');
        // we are all good
    } catch(e) {
        // something failed, as per the error details
    }
}
```